# RegisterClientScriptBlock is not working in new version of browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Why does the following code not work in newer versions of Chrome and Firefox?

```js
this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Close", "window.close()", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following:

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Your page name,this.GetType(),"Close","window.close();",true);